# KMAP Sum of Products - How to get the Simplified Function from the KMAP Table

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

I am answering a KMAP Sum of Products with don't care table but I don't know how to get the simplified function. Here's my progress:

**Problem: 
Q(C, O, D, E) = Σ(0,1,2,3,7,8,10) + d(5,6,11,15)**

[image]

The only remaining to solve is the simplified function which derives by encircling number 1's (sometimes with don't cares). How to get the simplified function from on this problem?

P.S. Not 100% sure if that is the right answer of encircling number 1s

Comment: What is the simplified function. I ask because your question phrasing confuses me such as *...answering a KMAP Sum of Products with...* i.e. how can you answer a KMAP thing? It's probably a language thing.

Comment: Hint: the corners can be group horizontally ***and*** vertically.